# How do I make 3D text using css?

Tags: css

I'm creating a website right now and obviously, I want it to look good, and I would be greatful if I had 3D text in it. Thanks for the help.
Also, this is the css that I have for my text right now:
`p, ol{ color: red; }`
And, some font-family which I couldn't find in my style.css.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. You can create a 3D post yourself by looking at this.
You can use `transform()`.
https://codepen.io/havardob/pen/PoPaWaE

Comment: more examples https://freefrontend.com/css-text-effects/

Comment: Cool, thanks. This will definitely help with my website.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose this method.
Create a HTML file. Take paragraph with a class name.

```
<p class="taxt3d">3D TEXT<p>
```

Add text shadow CSS property.

```
.text3d {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #17202A, 0 2px 0 #17202A,
    0 7px 0 #17202A, 0 8px 0 #17202A,
    0 11px 0 #17202A, 0 12px 0 #17202A;
}
```

I hope this will work properly.